# Shell script: how to pass arguments into racket that is interpreted in the racket session?

Tags: macos, shell, sh, racket, zsh

I am trying build a shell script to 1. Open the racket language interactive session using `racket` and 2. adding the appropriate language and version in the racket session via `require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme:2:2))`.

Rather than typing `racket`, waiting for it to load, then typing `require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme:2:2))`, I'd like to build a shell script to automate this.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The command line to achieve this is `racket -i -p dyoo/simply-scheme:2:2` (or alternatively with `-e` flag). It is then trivial to build in sh/bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

racket -i -p dyoo/simply-scheme:2:2
```

You can even write a script in Racket like this, which accept an argument to require any package:

```
;; repl.rkt

#! /usr/bin/env racket

(require racket/cmdline)
(require racket/system)

(define package (make-parameter ""))

(define parser
  (command-line
   #:usage-help
   "Start a racket REPL and require an initial package."

   #:once-each
   [("-p" "--package") PACKAGE
                    "Add an initial package to require."
                    (package PACKAGE)]

   #:args () (void)))


(define (run (package-name))
  (system (~a (printf "racket -i -p ~a" package-name))))

(run package)
```

And run `repl.rkt -p dyoo/simply-scheme:2:2`.

Alternative command is `racket -i -e '(require (planet "dyoo/simply-scheme:2:2"))'`

UPDATE: The shebang has been corrected per the comments.

Comment: The shebang `#!/usr/bin/bash` is unusual, and wrong for some platforms. Probably try `#!/bin/bash` or perhaps `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if you get "/usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" or similar.

Comment: @tripleee: or just use `#!/bin/sh -` which will work on anything remotely compliant.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you only use `sh` syntax, which of course this one does. Many beginners are surprised that `sh` and `bash` are two different shells with different feature sets (though Bash is a strict superset of `sh`).